# Select list of values from case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a variable `myvalue` that is a string parameter with either the value `"TRUE"` or `"TRUE,FALSE"`.

When `myvalue = "TRUE"` I want to select just `N/A`.  When `myvalue = "TRUE,FALSE"`, I want to select a list of values from 0 to 23 (representing discrete hours of the day) with each value its own row.

Here's what I have - what am I missing here? I want to be able to do this without storing anything in a table (temp or real). I'm getting syntax errors.

```
SELECT
CASE myvalue
WHEN "TRUE"
THEN "N/A"
WHEN "TRUE,FALSE" THEN (SELECT "0" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "1" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "2" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "3" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "4" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "5" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "6" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "7" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "8" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "9" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "10" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "11" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "12" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "13" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "14" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "15" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "16" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "17" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "18" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "19" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "20" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "21" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "22" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "23" FROM DUAL
                        )
END as optionz
FROM
DUAL
```

Error message: `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `Oracle`?  Your code is `Oracle` syntax (which would explain your unspecified syntax errors).

Comment: DUAL and MySQL? Anyhow, you're trying to do something very SQL-unlike. A case expression (not statement) returns one single value. Do a UNION instead, with one SELECT for N/A and one SELECT for the rest,

Comment: there are numerous sources online that state 'dual' is supported in mysql.

Comment: @Ted It would be more helpful if you actually posted what the "syntax errors" you're getting say.

Comment: When the value is  TRUE,FALSE you wil get an Oracle error "single row returns more than one row".

The subselect ends with 2 times from dual.

Comment: UNION SELECT "23" FROM DUAL
                        FROM DUAL). There are two FROM DUAL, remove one

Comment: What are you using your query for? If you use it to fill e.g. a listbox in your client, make the selection there and use two different queries.

Comment: @Solarflare for context - yes - that's exactly what I'm using it for, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Ted I mean: you probably have some place in your code where you fill your listbox, and for that you query the data first. If it's dataaware component (otherwise you could simply hardcode one case (or both)) and if `myvalue` is a variable in your code (and you will have to update the query whenever you change it), instead of using 1 query for both option, e.g. `$sql = "...(select" + $myValue + "..."`, you could use an `if` in your code, e.g. `if $myValue = "..." then $sql = "..." else $sql = "..."` and have 2 different querys depending on your value. (At least if that is what you are doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd try:

```
select x from  (select myValue as y) t join
    (select 'N/A' as x, 'TRUE' as y 
    union
    select '1' as x, "TRUE,FALSE" as y
    union
    select '2' as x, "TRUE,FALSE" as y
    /* keep adding your values here */
    ) t2
on t.y = t2.y;
```

This makes a join to something a bit like a temporary table, and will give you lots of rows for the 'TRUE/FALSE' case, and only one row for the 'TRUE' case, which is I think what you want.

Comment: The answer above from @juan-carlos-oropeza is probably better

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` return an expresion not a `SELECT` you **cant** return an `UNION`

THIS IS **OK**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2
            THEN '2'
            ELSE (SELECT 1 as d FROM DUAL)
       END as res
FROM DUAL;
```

THIS **ISNT OK**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2
            THEN '2'
            ELSE (SELECT 1 as d FROM DUAL UNION
                  SELECT 2 as d FROM DUAL 
                  )
       END as res
FROM DUAL;
```

You want **[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SLMD97498)**

```
--SELECT @myValue := 'TRUE';
SELECT @myValue := 'TRUE,FALSE';

SELECT val
FROM (SELECT "TRUE" as parameter, "N/A" as val FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "1" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "2" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "3" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "4" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "5" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "6" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "7" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "8" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "9" FROM DUAL UNION
      SELECT "TRUE,FALSE", "10" FROM DUAL 
     ) t
WHERE t.parameter = @myValue ;
```

Comment: How do I test this with myvalue/parameter as just a string "TRUE".
It doesn't seem to like `WHERE t."TRUE" = "TRUE,FALSE"`

Comment: Check again, I include a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit strange.. but perhaps this will work (if you are working with Oracle SQL):

```
SELECT HOURS_OF_DAY
from
(SELECT myvalue as myvalue FROM dual) a, 
(SELECT '0' hours_of_day  FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '1' FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT '2' FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT '3' FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT '4' FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT '5' FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT '6' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '7' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '8' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '9' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '10' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '11' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '12' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '13' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '14' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '15' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '16' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '17' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '18' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '19' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '20' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '21' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '22' FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT '23' FROM DUAL
                        ) b
WHERE myvalue = 'TRUE,FALSE'
```

Comment: How do I get my "N/A" in there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DUAL
WHERE
    [YourDataColumn] IN (SELECT
                        CASE
                            WHEN myvalue = 'TRUE' THEN 'N/A'
                            ELSE (SELECT 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
                        END AS X)
```

Comment: Error code 1096 - no tables used.  (I just replaced [YourDataColumn] with true.)

Comment: No, Replace [YourDataColumn] with the Column that has your value ("True" Or "True,False")

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
SELECT 'N/A' as optionz
FROM dual
WHERE myvalue = 'TRUE'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "0" as val FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "1" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "2" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "3" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "4" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "5" FROM DUAL
                        UNION SELECT "6" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "7" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "8" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "9" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "10" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "11" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "12" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "13" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "14" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "15" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "16" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "17" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "18" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "19" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "20" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "21" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "22" FROM DUAL 
                        UNION SELECT "23" FROM DUAL
                        ) t
FROM DUAL
WHERE myvalue <> 'TRUE';
```

Comment: where `myValue` come from? or is a variable?

Comment: It is a parameter to a report

Comment: @Ted shouldnt be `@myValue` ?

Comment: the syntax is weird - I'm using jasper studio so technically it will be $P(Flag)...

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Instead of the UNION chaining, do:

```
SELECT a FROM (
  SELECT 'N/A' AS a, 'TRUE' AS b, @a := -1
  UNION
  SELECT @a := @a +1 AS a, 'TRUE,FALSE' AS b, NULL FROM information_schema.PARAMETERS LIMIT 24
) t
WHERE t.b = @myValue;
```

using any table in your database guaranteed to have at least 24 records.

And with MySQL, you can drop the `FROM DUAL`

Comment: This is close, but I still get `Error code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`